# Kubernetes with web gui integrated with Active Directory

Tags: kubernetes, active-directory

Is there a web gui to kubernetes (on premises) that can be integrated with Active Directory (on premises, not Azure) authentication. This way RBAC would be integrated with Ad users.

Comment: You can find a lot of articles about integrating kubernetes with active directory e.g.: [Access your Kubernetes cluster with your Active Directory credentials](https://blog.inkubate.io/access-your-kubernetes-cluster-with-your-active-directory-credentials/) or [Authenticate Kubernetes Dashboard Users With Active Directory](https://computingforgeeks.com/kubernetes-and-active-directory-integration/). Does this aswer your question ?

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

*I'm posting an answer based on my comment for better readability.*

Such integration can be done using [dex - A federated OpenID Connect provider](https://github.com/dexidp/dex) project. In short:

> Dex is an identity service that uses  [OpenID
> Connect](https://openid.net/connect/)  to drive authentication for
> other apps.
>
> Dex acts as a portal to other identity providers through
> ["connectors."](https://github.com/dexidp/dex#connectors)  This lets
> dex defer authentication to LDAP servers, SAML providers, or
> established identity providers like GitHub, Google, and Active
> Directory. Clients write their authentication logic once to talk to
> dex, then dex handles the protocols for a given backend.

> Dex runs natively on top of any Kubernetes cluster using Custom
> Resource Definitions and can drive API server authentication through
> the OpenID Connect plugin. Clients, such as the
> [`kubernetes-dashboard`](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard)  and
> `kubectl`, can act on behalf of users who can login to the cluster
> through any identity provider dex supports.
>
> - More docs for running dex as a Kubernetes authenticator can be found  [here](https://dexidp.io/docs/kubernetes/).
> - You can find more about companies and projects, which uses dex,  [here](https://github.com/dexidp/dex/blob/master/ADOPTERS.md).

As this is quite extensive topic, there is no point of rewrite all the configuration steps here. You can find a lot of well written articles about integrating **kubernetes** with **Active Directory** using dex e.g.:

- [Access your Kubernetes cluster with your Active Directory credentials](https://blog.inkubate.io/access-your-kubernetes-cluster-with-your-active-directory-credentials/)
- [Authenticate Kubernetes Dashboard Users With Active Directory](https://computingforgeeks.com/kubernetes-and-active-directory-integration/)